# creating a custom search in android (inserting a search widget in the layout)

Tags: android, widget

How can I create a custom search within my android app layout?

I am able to use the search dialog that appears at the top of the activity window but I would like something similar to the image here:

[image: custom searchview]
http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/1298/customsearch.gif

If sample codes are available, I will appreciate so much.

Thank you.

Sorry about my english.

Comment: @ hey Joseph you can refer the this link for make searching in android http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Answer (score 0):

make a search layout in res folder as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="search"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```